# C# Object selection and manipulation

Tags: c#, oop

**What my goal is:**
Create multiple Objects (villages in my case) and have some attributes, which I want to change to change very often.

**Whats the curent status**
I create an Object with variables.

**So what's the problem now?**
I created village00(static ID) with a changeable name(default: "village00"+i) and village01 with the name: "BigBadCity". 
But I now want to change a specific variable of the object(maybe a farm) to a level +1. So how can I select the village which I want to change the variables of?

**Info**

Programming language C#

I have searched for a solution but found nothing accurate

UX

Not new to C# but to OOP


I am programming "Tribal Wars 1" ("Die Stämme" in mother-tongue) in C# ... if my description what I want was to bad ;)

**code of my class**

```
namespace CS_DieStaemme
{
    class villageObjekt
    {
        //Default constructor
        public villageObjekt()
        {
            str_villageCount = "village";//count all villages
            str_name = "village";   //default name
            sho_points = 0;         //Start points
            byt_cord_X = 0;         //default cords x (need to change later)
            byt_cord_Y = 0;         //default cords y (need to change later)

            sho_wood = 0;
            sho_clay = 0;
            sho_iron = 0;

            byte_mainBuilding = 1;
            byte_storage = 1;
            byte_farm = 1;
            byte_church = 0;
            byte_casern = 0;
            byte_stable = 0;
            byte_workshop = 0;
            byte_statue = 0;
            byte_market = 0;

        }

        //Default constructor
        public villageObjekt(
                       byte village_byt_villageCount,//village count
                       byte village_byt_cord_X,    //Village cord x    (ex. 245)
                       byte village_byt_cord_Y     /*Village cord y    (ex. 632)*/)
        {
            str_villageCount += village_byt_villageCount; //count up village
            byt_cord_X = village_byt_cord_X; //set cords
            byt_cord_Y = village_byt_cord_Y; // set cods
        }

        //Member variables
        public string str_villageCount;
        public string str_name;    //Village name      (ex. village012)
        public short sho_points;   //Village points    (ex. 567pt)
        private byte byt_cord_X;    //Village cord x    (ex. 245)
        private byte byt_cord_Y;    //Village cord y    (ex. 632)

        //Production variables
        public short sho_wood;
        public short sho_clay;
        public short sho_iron;

        //Buildings variables
        public byte byte_mainBuilding;
        public byte byte_storage = 1;
        public byte byte_farm = 1;
        public byte byte_church = 0;
        public byte byte_casern = 0;
        public byte byte_stable = 0;
        public byte byte_workshop = 0;
        public byte byte_statue = 0;
        public byte byte_market = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: [If your question doesn't include code, are you sure it shouldn't?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/4934172)

Comment: I barely understood what's your problem, but if I'm correct, you want to change a value of a member of the object you've created?

Comment: One reason the site really really really wants you to provide code is that it cuts thru language barriers.  It also can add clarity.  What kind of objects are these?  In a way they sound like UI objects, but that is not certain.  most likely rather than `an Object with variables` create some properties then change them as you wish.  If that is a problem provide code which illustrates how and why it is a problem.  As is, my inclination is that this is too broad.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and then submit a [mcve]. Also, please, *please*, get rid of those `byte_`, `str_`, `sho_` etc. prefixes. They provide zero value to your code and hinder readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could store all villages in a List `var villages = new List<villageObjekt>();` and then select and edit the village you want with:

```
var villageName = "<Insert the name of the village you want to edit>";
var villageToEdit = villages.First(v => v.str_name == villageName);
//edit the village
villageToEdit.byte_farm++; //farm level-up
villageToEdit. ...
```

With this list you have to add a village to the list with `villages.Add(village);` or you create a village inside that list  `villages.Add(new villageObjekt());`.

Comment: Thank you. Your awnser helped me a lot.